# What's wrong with my htaccess-configuration?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my htaccess-file for the web-root:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/html
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Expire images header
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A24592000
ExpiresByType image/png A24592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A24592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A24592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A24592000
ExpiresByType text/css A24592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A24592000

RewriteEngine On

#do not rewrite for subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?legendaily\.com$

#redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#only rewrite if it's not a file and not /login/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/

#rewrite /a/1 to /index.php?action=a&urlId=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&urlId=$2 [L,QSA]

#rewrite /a to /index.php?action=a
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]

AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

and this is the one I use in the /min-directory where I use http://code.google.com/p/minify/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# You may need RewriteBase on some servers
#RewriteBase /min

# rewrite URLs like "/min/f=..." to "/min/?f=..."
RewriteRule ^([bfg]=.*)  index.php?$1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
# In case AddOutputFilterByType has been added
SetEnv no-gzip
</IfModule>
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. The Google-Site-Verification-File in the root can't be accessed by Google because it's rewritten
2. I would like to use subdomains for cookie-freeness, so I've added i.domain.com and s.domain.com to my server-configuration, but if I access s.domain.com/min, it's redirected to the web-root.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
#do not rewrite for subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?legendaily\.com$
```

Probably needs to be changed to:

```
#do not rewrite for subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.+\.legendaily\.com$ [NC]
```

So that it matches the next rule excludes subdomains

Conditions only get applied to the immediately following rewrite rule so you need to repeat the ones that apply to more than one rule. The last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Doesn't have any conditions, and thus will blindly rewrite everything to `/index.php`, including files that exist. So you need at least the `!-f` check:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I still get the following answer from http://s.domain.com/min/b=js&f=fastclick.js,bootstrap.min.js,jquery.masonry.min.js,exif2.js,bootstrap-tagmanager.js,custom.js,editor.js,preview.js:

<?php
/**
 * Front controller for default Minify implementation
 * 
 * DO NOT EDIT! Configure this utility via config.php and groupsConfig.php
 * 
 * @package Minify
 */

Comment: @RaphaelJeger As in why you are seeing raw php code? That has nothing to do with the rewrite rules.